# DataTable. How to stop a search.dt event from being fired from inside the event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, event-handling, jquery-events

I have this code, and when I detect the filter typed by the user contains some bad characters like `'` I don't want it to reach the Server.

I have this simplified code:

```
$table.on('search.dt', function () {
    var value = getValue();
    if (antiHackingHelper.isValid(value)) {
    } else { // Contains charakter like "'" so don't call the server with this bad filter
        // Don't send the request to the server with a filter with bad characters
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prevent the search from being performed at this point. `search.dt` *is* already broadcasted at the time your `$table.on('search.dt' listener...` is executed, and it is not part of a chain where you can cancel the search "upstream".

Instead you could prevent illegal characters from being entered in the filter box in the first place :

```js
var illegalChars = "',.-*)(";
$('.dataTables_filter input').on('keypress', function(e) {
   if (~illegalChars.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode))) {
     console.log('Illegal char entered, aborting');
     return false;
   }
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/q39c3c0k/**